# Omit a AND statement if a variable is blank or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a WHERE statement

```
Where [State] in (@StateCode)
And LocationCode in (@LCode)
```

But sometimes that @LCode will be blank.  If I run it with a blank, I get 0 rows returned.  If I run it WITHOUT the "And LocationCode..." I get results.
What I'm trying to accomplish is that if the @LCode is blank, don't use the "And Location..." statement.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
Where [State] in (@StateCode)
AND  (LocationCode in (@LCode) OR @LCode = '' OR @LCode IS NULL)
```

This will return results if @LCode is an empty string or @LCode is null.